# Evaluate $\int_c {{{\tan z} \over z}dz}$ using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Using residue theorem, evaluate the following; $C:\left| {z - 1} \right| = 2$
>   $$\int_c {{{\tan z} \over z}dz}$$

I want you guys to check my answer.Is it correct?
$$\displaylines{
  {\mathop{\rm Res}\nolimits} (f(z),0) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to 0} (z - 0) \times {{\tan z} \over z} \cr 
   = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to 0} \tan z \cr 
   = 0 \cr} $$

Comment: You are missing a pole that occurs at $z = \pi/2$.

Comment: And zero is not a real pole, pun intended.

Answer (score 2):

The function has a removable singularity at the origin since
$$
f(z)=\frac{\tan z}{z} = \frac{\sin z}{z}\frac{1}{\cos z},
$$
and 
$$
\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\sin z}{z} = 1.
$$
So the singularities you need to worry about are the zeros of $\cos z$, *i.e*, $z=\pm\,\pi /2$. Then, using the the poles of $\sec z$ are of first order and the positive orientation is counterclockwise:
$$
\begin{align}
I &= -\left(res_{\frac{\pi}{2}}\,f + res_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\,f \right)\\
&= -\left(\lim_{z\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(z-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\frac{\tan z}{z} + \lim_{z\to-\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(z+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\frac{\tan z}{z} \right)\\
&= -\frac{2}{\pi}\left(\lim_{z\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(z-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\sec z + \lim_{z\to-\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(z+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\sec z \right) \\
&= -\frac{2}{\pi}\left(\lim_{z\to 0}z\sec  \left(z+\frac{\pi}{2}\right) + \lim_{z\to 0}z\sec\left(z-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \right) \\
&= -\frac{2}{\pi}\left(-\lim_{z\to 0}z\csc z+ \lim_{z\to 0}z\csc z\right) \\
&= 0
\end{align}
$$

**Edit:** A simpler way to do this is using that if $g$ is holomorphic in $z_0$ and $f$ has a simple pole in $z_0$, then $res_{z_0} (gf) = g(z_0)\,res_{z_0}f$. Then, observe that $\sec z$ is an even function and use: [The Residues of an even function or an odd function on $U$ subset open symmetric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972524/the-residues-of-an-even-function-or-an-odd-function-on-u-subset-open-symmetric)